# shared_ptr vs. new operator: which one to use

Tags: c++, task, shared-ptr, continuations, ppl

In the function below I have made use of `http_client` from cpprestsdk (https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) to make http requests to a network camera. The function below is probably a callback called by the lcm library (http://lcm-proj.github.io/) when a certain request is made.

I had problems with line 11. I was previously using the new operator:

```
auto init_session_response = new init_session_response_t;
```

to create the pointer and manually delete it just before exiting the function.
  But I got a access violation exception when trying to modify the `init_session_response` object in the pplx task continuation at line 49.

```
init_session_response->status_code =
              ptz_camera::status_codes_t::OK;
```

This problem went away when I started using std::shared_ptr. Can someone explain to me why using shared_ptr solved the problem? Should the http_client* also be created using std::shared_ptr?

```
1 void lcm_handler::on_init_session_req(const lcm::ReceiveBuffer* rbuff,
2   const std::string& channel,
3   const ptz_camera::init_session_request_t* req)
4 {
5     std::cout << "Received init session req on channel: " << channel << 
6       "; Camera: " << req->ip_address << std::endl;
7 
8   auto ip_address = req->ip_address;
9 
10    // Note use of std::shared_ptr
11  auto init_session_response = make_shared<ptz_camera::init_session_response_t>();
12  
13  auto key_position = this->ip_client_map.find(ip_address);
14  if (key_position == ip_client_map.end())
15  {
16      std::cout << "Creating a new client for the ip: "
17          << req->ip_address << endl;
18
19      wstring username = this->convert_to_wstring(req->username);
20      wstring password = this->convert_to_wstring(req->password);
21
22      wstring main_uri = L"http://" + convert_to_wstring(ip_address);
23      auto config = http_client_config();
24      auto login = credentials(username, password);
25      config.set_credentials(login);
26      config.set_timeout(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
27
28      http_client* client = new http_client(main_uri, config);
29      std::cout << "Client created...\n";
30
31      uri_builder uri = uri_builder(U("/") + uri_constants::stw_cgi).
32          append_path(uri_constants::attributes_cgi).append_path(uri_constants::attributes);
33
34      auto request = uri.to_string();
35  
36      client->request(methods::GET, request)
37          .then([this, ip_address, client, init_session_response]
38              (pplx::task<http_response> request_task) -> pplx::task<wstring>
39      {
40          try 
41          {
42              auto response = request_task.get();
43              if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
44              {
45                  std::cout << "Saving client...";
46                  this->ip_client_map[ip_address] = client;
47                  std::cout << "success.\n";
48
49                  init_session_response->status_code =
50                  ptz_camera::status_codes_t::OK;
51              }
52
53              else
54              {
55                  cout << "GET request to client failed! HTTP Error: "
56                      << response.status_code() << std::endl;
57
58                  init_session_response->status_code =
59                      ptz_camera::status_codes_t::ERR;
60              }
61
62              return response.extract_string();
63          }
64              
65          catch (const exception& e)
66          {
67              cout << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << endl;
68              return create_task([e, this]() -> wstring
69              {
70                  return convert_to_wstring(e.what());
71              });
72          }               
73
74      })
75          .then([init_session_response, this](wstring response)
76      {
77          string n = this->convert_to_string(response);
78          init_session_response->response_message = n;
79      });
80  }
81
82
83  else
84  {
85      string message = "Client for ip: " + req->ip_address + " already exists\n";
86      cout << message << endl;
87      init_session_response->response_message = message;
88      init_session_response->status_code = ptz_camera::status_codes_t::OK;
89  }   
90
91  this->lcm->publish(ptz_camera_channels::init_session_res_channel,
92      init_session_response.get());   
93}
```

Comment: `shared_ptr` and `new` are not mutually exclusive, though it is good practice to generally keep them that way with `make_shared`.

Comment: keep in mind with `delete` the consequences are instantaneous (more or less) - the objects cease to be valid. this is relevant when you're setting up a callback / task that will need to refer to the value after `delete` which could be outside of the procedure allocating the object (such as a lambda using the address as a captured value).

Comment: Its probably better to post the code that *doesn't work* if you want us to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Also consider using `std::unique_ptr` rather than `std::shared_ptr` if you never intend to share the pointer's ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get violation access error, you must have deleted the pointer in some place in your code (e.g. in some `then` lambdas), but you did not post your code using raw pointer so I can not say which line.

By using `std::shared_ptr`, when it's passed to the lambda, it's captured by value, so it increase the `use_count` and ensures that `init_session_response` is valid and not destructed in the labmda, which solves the issue.